# How can I replace this brake line?

Tags: brakes

This picture shows you the brake line. It's on a 2002 Ford Escape. I changed the shoes a few days ago and I think I yanked on it or something. Anyways today while driving all of a sudden the brake pedal went limp so I think it finally burst.

I've never done a brake line before. Do I need to buy special tools for this little line segment? It almost looks like it just bolts in. I haven't taken a close look because it's wet and I went inside to cry.

What tools do I need? What is the name of this part? If this will be expensive can I get the part from the junkyard? Oh yeah, how do I do this? Thanks.

Oh yeah, would it be possible to put a home made bleeder screw on this line? I sheared the one on the caliper off so there's no way to bleed this line. This part is just a nice to have though.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disconnect the metal pipes from both ends of the flexible pipe.

Then the flexible pipe can be removed.

As for special tools a flare nut spanner is a very good investment as otherwise you will round off the hex as the flare nut metal is softer than normal nuts.

For the bleed nipple, either drill out and remove the broken one or buy a new caliper. Otherwise you will end up with a soft or no pedal as there will be air trapped in the caliper.

Don’t try bodging it as brakes are a safety item and you might put other people’s lives in danger.

Comment: Okay, yeah I got it. The clip wasn't too hard. The metal line was bending as I loosened the nut so I googled how to get it off without shearing the brake line. ...that didn't work at all so what I ended up doing was taking the bottom off first and that let me turn the hose instead of the nut. No break fluid came out which was concerning but I filled it back up and kind of tried bleeding it by pressing the peddle and tightening the hose. That probably didn't do much but anyways it seems to be working. No leaks. The brake line fortunately never sheared so I think I'm good. Thanks for your instru